# Fortran to SAS code conversiton

Tags: fortran, sas

I want to create 1, 2, 3 dimensional variables/arrays inside of proc iml. My code looks following:

```
proc iml;
start Mean1(x);         /*this is 1 dimension variable/array*/
Mean1(x)=sum(x)/dim(x);
finish;

proc iml;
start Mean2(x);         /*this is 2 dimension variable/array*/
Mean1(x)=sum(x)/dim(x);
finish;

proc iml;
start Mean3(x);         /*this is 3 dimension variable/array*/
Mean1(x)=sum(x)/dim(x);
finish;
```

I tried to do like this:

```
proc iml;
declare double x[dim(n),dim(n)];
start Mean2(x);         /*this is 2 dimension variable or array*/
Mean1(x)=sum(x)/dim(a, x);
finish;
```

But it's not working. Could you help me?

Comment: Are you using IML Studio with the IML+ language or the base PROC IML? Which version of SAS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to know here.

1. SAS IML arrays are 1 indexed C style row major arrays.  Not column
   major like Fortran.
2. To my knowledge, there are no 3 dimensional arrays in IML.  Always possible I am mistaken.
3. All numbers in SAS are doubles.
4. IML has nice reduction operators that make means easy
   and very fast.

To declare a matrix/array, use the J(nrow,ncol,fill) function:

```
proc iml;
x = J(10,5,1); /*Declare a 10x5 matrix filled with 1s*/
x = normal(x);  /*Fills matrix X with random numbers, uses the values in X as the seed*/

mean_all = x[:]; /*mean over all values in x*/
mean_col = x[:,];/*mean of each column */
mean_row = x[,:];/*mean of each row */

print mean_all;
print mean_col;
print mean_row;

quit;
```

I highly recommend going through the IML documentation.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/iml/index.html

Comment: I'm no IML expert, but I agree - there is not generally a way to directly handle 3+ dimension arrays/matrices.  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.6563&rep=rep1&type=pdf goes into some detail about how you can do so using a `levels` vector, but I'm not sure how easy it is to transform that into what you're doing here.